# combination/induction question, number of ways you can divide n people into groups of 1 or 2

Tags: combinatorics, induction

this is homework!!

Let $n \geq 1$ be an integer and consider $n$ people $P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_n$. 
Let $A_n$ be the number of ways these $n$ people can be divided into 
groups, such that each group consists of either one or two people.

Determine $A_1$, $A_2$, and $A_3$.

Prove that for each integer $n \geq 3$, 
$[ A_n = A_{n-1} + (n-1) \cdot A_{n-2}]$

Ok now, 
I've determined here I've only been giving a left hand side of the expression as I still need an algebraic eq'n to determine what $A_n$ would be, I can then use induction to prove the eq'n above is this thinking correct?

next, I have sort of figured out what the expression would be equal too but I'm having a hell of a time to create an equation for

$A_k = (1 + _{k}C_{2}(1 + \frac{_{k-2}C_{2}}{2!}(1+\frac{_{k-4}C_{2}}{3!}(1 + ...))))$

my idea here is basically count the number of combinations where there are no goups consisting of 2 ppl, then add that with all combinations with 1 group consisting of 2 ppl (the rest 1), and so forth up to floor(n/2) <- max number of groups consisting of 2 people,
yeah some help to point me in the correct direction would be awesome

**Edit**

im used to induction questions being in the form 
The function $f : N \rightarrow Z$ is recursively defined as follows:
[ \begin{array}{ccl} 
      f(0) & = & 3 , \\ 
      f(n) & = & 2 \cdot f(n-1) - \left( f(n-1) \right)^2 
               \mbox{ if $n \geq 1$.} 
   \end{array} 
]
Prove that $f(n) = 1 - 2^{2^n}$ for all integers $n \geq 1$.
($2^{2^n}$ means $2$ to the power of $2^n$.)

and now I would show that $f(k+1) = 2 \cdot f(k) - \left( f(k) \right)^2   = 1 - 2^{2^{k+1}}$ where $n = k+1$

now i have a left and right side of the equation in which I can show each other are equal.

**back to the question at hand....**

simple stating adding 1 to k on both sides and saying because
$[ A_k = A_{k-1} + (k-1) \cdot A_{k-2}]$, then jumping to 
$[ A_{k+1} = A_{k} + (k) \cdot A_{k-1}]$ doesn't feel right to me I haven't shown or proved anything, am I incorrect in this belief?

Comment: The idea of mathematical induction is to only look at the case n, assume it is true (in this case $A_n=A_{n-1}+(n-1)\cdot A_{n-2}$) and deduce the "same" formula for $A_{n+1}$ from that. You definitely don't want to construct an explicit equation for each $k$, use what you know

Comment: If that's what you have, you are done, that's exactly what you want to prove

Comment: mmk well the base case is done that was easy, now im working ont he induction I have $A_{k+1} = A_{k} + k*A_{k_1}$ however I'm then confused what the next step would be as $A_{k+1} = (k+1)A_{k-1} + (k-1)A_{k-2} = kA_{k} + A_{k} = (k + 1)A_{k}$ and now I'm lost

Comment: Please edit your first comment and put your next comment in it, and afterwards remove your last two comments to keep the comment section clean. I don't really see why you would need to take a next step after you know $A_{k+1}=A_k+k\cdot A_k$, simply substituting $k+1$ to $k$ gives exactly what you want to prove

Comment: i edited the entire post to help clear things up, it wouldn't let me edit the previous comments, so I deleted most of them to tidy things up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n=1$: $P_1$ must be alone, hence $A_1=1$
$n=2$: $P_1$ and $P_2$ are grouped or not, hence $A_2=2$

When you add another, $P_n$, there are two cases:

$P_n$ gets to be alone. Now you have to divide the rest which can be done in $A_{n-1}$ ways.
$P_n$ groups with one of the $n-1$ other people. Now dividing the rest can be done in $A_{n-2}$ ways.

That is $A_n=A_{n-1}+(n-1)\cdot A_{n-2}$

From the above we have $A_3=2+2\cdot1$

Comment: this isn't exactly how I need to answer this question, just based on the first part where they ask for the first 3 values, it seems to be just setting me up to use induction. with that said this is a great answer!